# Can't delete EC2 instance or ECS volume

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to remove an EC2 instance that was added by mistake while trying to figure out how to deploy my API code.

Every time I terminate it, another one appears.

I now have a list of terminated instances, and 1 too many running instances.

I also have an extra EBS instance which I need to remove but can't because the Delete option is disabled.

When I read the docs it says this should work, there is no mention of the delete option not being available.

I can detach the volume, but then another one appears.

This question is similar to another one. That one suggests the problem may be caused by a cluster, but I don't have any. I followed the instructions just in case but none are listed.

Comment: How did you create the EC2 instance in the first place? There may be an autoscaling group that is recreating it.

Comment: Spot on. I just needed to know what to look for. If this were an answer I'd accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: I can re-post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely an autoscaling group that is recreating it. Open the EC2 console and click *Auto Scaling Groups* in the left-side menu. Delete the ASG and any remaining instances should automatically be terminated.